# Show me the selected toggle button in Angular 4 and the other slice

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have made toggle buttons like component in Angular so I can use everywhere I need, but I am trying to solve something and I need your help.

I need only to show me the selected toggle button so the other toggle button don't show.
When I click in the selected toggle button then show me the other toggle buttons for example like expand and collapse, if I click the selected toggle button than show me the everything what is in that array.
The selected toggle button comes from another component with ngModel which tells by the component which is selected
I have tried slice but didn't work.

This is the component of toggle button.

```
<div id="toggle-button" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start end">
    <label [style.width]="labelWidth" [style.paddingRight]="label.length > 0 ? '10px' : '0'">
        {{label}}
    </label>
    <div *ngFor="let option of options | slice:0:1; let first = first; let last = last" [ngClass]="{'first': first, 'last': last, 'selected': option.value === value, 'divider' : !last, 'clickable': !readonly, 'not-selectable': readonly}"
     [style.width]="optionWidth" (click)="select(option.value)" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <span (click)="options.length">{{option.text}}</span>

    </div>
</div>

export class ToggleButtonComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() options: ToggleOption[] = []
    @Input() label = ""
    @Input() value: any
    @Input() labelWidth = ""
    @Input() optionWidth = ""
    @Input() readonly = false
    @Output() toggle = new EventEmitter<any>()
    onChangeCallback: (selected: any) => void = () => { }
    onTouchedCallback: (selected: any) => void = () => { }
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.value)

    }

    writeValue(selected: any): void {
        this.value = selected
    }

    registerOnChange(callback: (selected: any) => void): void {
        this.onChangeCallback = callback
    }

    registerOnTouched(callback: (selected: any) => void): void {
        this.onTouchedCallback = callback
    }

    select(selected: any) {
        if (!this.readonly) {
            this.value = selected
            this.onChangeCallback(selected)
            this.onTouchedCallback(selected)
            this.toggle.emit(selected)
        }
    }
}

export interface ToggleOption {
    text: string
    value: any
}
```

And this is another component where I declare the toggle buttons.

```
readonly categoryOptions: ToggleOption[] = [
    { text: "BUS", value: 0 },
    { text: "BOS", value: 1 },
    { text: "BIS", value: 2 }
]
<app-toggle-button label="Category" labelWidth="75px" [options]="categoryOptions" [(ngModel)]="valueItem.category"></app-toggle-button>
```

Comment: Can elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: @SunilSingh I have explained and I have elaborate my question, if you have any question more please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Aim

The aim to have multiple toggle buttons with multiple options.

> ### Solution

1. You need to have `toggleState` variable to show/hide other buttons.
2. A variable `value` to check for current selected buttons which.

You just need to tweak in your ts and html file as -

### ts

Add new variable called `toggleState` to hold toggle state and change the state whenever `select` `function` is called.

```
 toggleState = false;
 select(selected: any) {
        if (!this.readonly) {
            this.value = selected
            this.onChangeCallback(selected)
            this.onTouchedCallback(selected)
            this.toggle.emit(selected)
            this.toggleState = !this.toggleState; //<-- toggle state here
        }
    }
```

### html

Just check for current value and toggle state using the syntax `*ngIf="option.value == value || toggleState`

```
"

 <div id="toggle-button" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start end">
        <label [style.width]="labelWidth" [style.paddingRight]="label.length > 0 ? '10px' : '0'">
            {{label}}
        </label>
        <div *ngFor="let option of options; let first = first; let last = last" [ngClass]="{'first': first, 'last': last, 'selected': option.value === value, 'divider' : !last, 'clickable': !readonly, 'not-selectable': readonly}"
         [style.width]="optionWidth" (click)="select(option.value)" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
 *ngIf="option.value == value || toggleState">
            <span (click)="options.length">{{option.text}}</span>
    
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Toggle false on click anywhere else

You can use the `HostListener` to handle this -

```
 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public documentClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    const targetElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
 
      // Check if the click was outside the element
      if (targetElement && !this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement)) {
 
         this.toggleState = false; //<-- you can emit if required.
      }
  }
```

> Note : Ideally this kind scenario should be handle through Directive.

Comment: This is working thank you so much I didn't realize I need a ngIf and toggle state

Comment: Can you provide when I click somewhere this toggle state must be false ?

Comment: Somewhere means anywhere outside of toggle ?

Comment: Yes that i mean

Comment: It is working man but I have another question for this, can I make for example an Input where we can decide if we want to close the toggle buttons or not. For example if is true we cal expand and collapse if is false cannot collapse and expand

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Pipe`, so like this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5u5wn1